# AdaptiveCard button with Action.submit not working on android device

Tags: android, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have developed a bot that has an invite card when the user did not add the bot yet, it will return the following JSON to render the AdaptiveCard:

```
{
    body: [
      {
        text: translations['MsTeams::AdaptiveCardBodyLooksLikeTryToUseApp'],
        wrap: true,
        type: 'TextBlock',
      },
      {
        text: translations['MsTeams::AdaptiveCardBodyNeedToInviteApp'],
        wrap: true,
        type: 'TextBlock',
      },
    ],
    actions: [
      {
        data: {
          actionId: 'INSTALL_BOT_SUBMIT',
          cancel: true,
        },
        title: translations['MsTeams::Cancel'],
        type: 'Action.Submit',
      },
      {
        data: {
          msteams: {
            justInTimeInstall: true,
          },
          actionId: 'INSTALL_BOT_SUBMIT',
        },
        title: translations['MsTeams::Invite'],
        type: 'Action.Submit',
      },
    ],
    type: 'AdaptiveCard',
    version: '1.0',
  }
```

And it's working fine on desktop, browser, and iOS devices, but not working on Android devices.
Here is the device & app info:
Android device version: 8.0.0
MS teams app version: 1416/1.0.0.2021010802

Comment: we are looking into this issue and will update you soon.

Comment: Can we discuss this on call? Please write to us at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com

Comment: Hi @Jeff Wu, Could you please try this [sample code](https://github.com/Trinetra-MSFT/89.teams-just-in-time-installation). Let us know if the issue still persists, We can discuss this over call.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea, but I see lots of hanging commas (e.g. `type: 'TextBlock',`). It might be that the Android parser is stricter on this - try remove them and test again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still does not work.